# Mule - JMS (ActiveMQ) Reconnection

Tags: groovy, jms, mule, activemq-classic, retrypolicy

This is my mule **flow 1**:

```
HTTP > Payload String > Logger > JMS /normalqueue
```

The **first flow** has an `error handling`:

`File` (Write a **file per message** handled)

**Flow 2**:

```
JMS /normalqueue > Logger
```

**Recovery flow** (Invoked with a **groovy script**):

```
File (Read file) > File to String > Flow reference (To First Flow again)
```

This is the XML from Mule:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="admin" password="admin" brokerURL="tcp://192.168.198.131:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" persistentDelivery="true">
    <reconnect blocking="false" frequency="6000"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
<file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="C:\errors" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="lab-file-catchFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="Started message: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="activemq" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\errors" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
<flow name="flow-recovery" initialState="stopped" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\errors" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <logger message=" Recovery message: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <flow-ref name="lab-file-catchFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
<flow name="lab-file-catchFlow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="activemq" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
<flow name="lab-file-catchFlow1" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/modify" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[            if(muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('flow-recovery').isStopped())
             {
              muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('flow-recovery').start();
              return 'Started';
             } else
             {
             muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('flow-recovery').stop();
             return 'Stopped';
             }]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

1. I stop service from `ActiveMQ`, it store a file with the messages from the error handling and I receive the typical error:

> Cannot process event as "Active_MQ" is stopped

2. Then, I run the `ActiveMQ service` again and start the recovery flow with a groovy script. That flow recover all messages, converts to string and return to the first flow to requeue.

The problem is that mule doesn't detect when service is running again, I need to restart the mule project to detect it.

Is there any way **auto detect** when the activeMQ is running again with Mule?

Comment: Did you check this answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187943/how-to-find-out-if-jms-connection-is-there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `<reconnect-forever/>`, Mule will keep re-trying to connect to `ActiveMQ`

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="admin" password="admin" brokerURL="tcp://192.168.198.131:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" persistentDelivery="true">
    <reconnect-forever/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
```