# How to check JMS connection health

Tags: java, jms

This is similar to [How to find out if JMS Connection is there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187943/how-to-find-out-if-jms-connection-is-there/36077076?noredirect=1#comment59801447_36077076)

In `JMS` it is easy to find out if a connection is lost, a exception happens with exception listener. But how do I find out if the connection is healthy?

Scenario: I use `JMS` to communicate with my server and I want to monitor health of my connection. I run a periodic job for this.

Does JMS has a way to check if connection is healthy?

Eg. something like

`connection.isConnected()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a TransportListener (http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener.html).

There is also some methods you could use on the ActiveMQConnection class : `isClosed()`, `isClosing()`, `isStarted()`, ...

Btw, checking the connection state is the job of the jms client, not the application's job. If this is for monitoring purpose, you should rather use JMX or even advisory messages.

Comment: I am looking for a more generic info for standard JMS not for ActiveMQ specifically. Also I know it's a job of JMS client, that's why I want to know if there are any APIs for this in JMS ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in standard JMS, simply because it's the client's job, so the API is delegating this job to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Because a connection to JMS provider could break any time,for example when the application makes send or receive call. So it's not guaranteed that isConnected() type of call will connection availability. Instead I would choose to make the API call itself and handle any exceptions thrown. If it's a connection broken exception, then do re-connect or use automatic reconnection option provided by MQ JMS client itself.